# Импорт данных из excel в delphi

Tags: запрос, sqlite, delphi, sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как средствами delphi, используя sql запрос импортировать таблицу excel в базу данных sqlite?

Comment: Я если не изменяет склероз, то вроде через ODBC (источник -- лист excel)

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Не знаете, как выбрать данные из Excel? Или как написать запрос добавления записей? Или как работать с sqlite3 из Delphi?

Comment: я не знаю как написать запрос...

Comment: `select * from [Лист1$]` [тут подробнее](http://citforum.ru/programming/windows/excel_faq/part5.shtml#5.03)